# Use Angular 2 with .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api2

I started to take in consideration the possibility to use Angular 8 in new projects instead of Knockout.js, within ASP.NET WebApi2 for SPA.

But the real question is there a way to use Angular 8 with ASP.NET or you are basically bonded to ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core, JAVA, PhP, nodeJS or any other backend. You create the APIs in the backend and Angular only consumes it.

Angular simply doesn't care in which Framework the backend APIs are written.